# asp.net textbox to html page data

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

Hi I'm a bit rusty with this again, I have a user profile web page and I'm working on making a wall posting system, I can do it the crappy n easiest way: textbox to listbox and then save the listbox as a text document for retrieval when the client logs in again.

But id like to write it to the HTML code or something of that nature. Like those div containers so my style sheet is applied to the data being posted.

Could anyone give me a head start to this?

Comment: Try to explain your problem in a bit better, maybe even with a couple of lines of code.

Comment: see how we are speaking with the "add comment" im trying to create a dumbed down version of this. All i want to try do is on click event "button1" add text from "textbox" to a div html container in asp.net

Comment: or to something of that effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with jQuery

```
$('button').click(function(){
var x = $('textarea').val();
$('div').html(x);
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/dzert/

Answer (score 1):

You know from where you need to copy (sorry... take inspiration) your functionality.

1. Have a text box
2. User submits the data...
3. Add it to DB and either return the same data and add new table row below the previous one
   or just on client add extra "TR" below the previous "TR".

It will require jQuery or any other similar thing. You have SO, dissect it using Firebug and build your own version of it.